# Current User in .NET 5

Tags: c#, .net-5, identity, claims

I am using .NET 5 and identity 4.
I have very strange error when I want to get current userId, or claims. I can't get current user in Api controller, but Odata controller return normally user's data and claims..

So, this code I type in both controllers:

```
 ClaimsPrincipal user = User;
        if (user != null)
        {
            string userId = user.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "sub").FirstOrDefault()?.Value;
        }
```

In that example I need to get userID in api controller. I get userID in odata controller without any problem.

I google lot of time and now I don't have imagine and I ask you for help.
Has anyone had a similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

I forget to set [Authorize] on Api controller

```
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;

    [Authorize]
    [ApiController]
    public class TestController: ControllerBase
```